# ruleset iptables- user defined chains

Tags: iptables, firewall, ip6tables

I am very new in iptables. Learning to use them. I got a hang of some basic commands from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo. However, I didnt find good explanations of examples of a ruleset file which can be applied using the ip6tables-retore file.
For instance could someone explain the following user-defined chain below:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP 
:FORWARD DROP 
:OUTPUT DROP 
:userChain1 -

-A userChain1 -m limit --limit 4/sec -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
-A userChain1 -j DROP   

COMMIT
```

I understand in what context INPUT, OUTPUT and FORWARD chains are used. When will this userChain1 be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever packets are targeted/sent to it. For example by a rule like:

`ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1:21 -j userChain1`

The two rules:

```
-A userChain1 -m limit --limit 4/sec -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
-A userChain1 -j DROP
```

Means for the first 4 packets per second a response is sent, (REJECT target) and everything past that is just dropped with no response (DROP target).

Comment: Thanks brian. So if I use 
        
        ip6table -A INPUT -j userChain1
This will send all the incoming traffic to userChain1? Also if there is a case when a rule prior to this is matched, lets say -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1:21 -j AnotherChain, in that case the following rule will be checked or will be ignored?